# How to fetch data from URL and then store it in AsyncStorage in React Native?

Tags: json, react-native, fetch, asyncstorage

I'm trying to fetch data from URL and then store it in AsyncStorage in React Native.

This is screen where "magic" happens:

```
class CardsScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: null,
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        return fetch(REQUEST_URL)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({
                    isLoading: false,
                    dataSource: responseData,
                });
            })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        });
    }

    render() {

        if (netStatus) {

            if (this.state.isLoading) {
                return (
                    <View style={styles.container}>
                        <ActivityIndicator/>
                    </View>
                )
            } else {

                let data = this.state.dataSource.map((val, key) => {
                    return <View key={key} style={styles.itemWrapper}>
                        <View style={styles.titleWrapper}>
                            <Text style={styles.content}>{val.type}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.title}>{val.title}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.content}>{val.date}</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.imageWrapper}>
                            <Image
                                style={styles.image}
                                source={{uri: val.image}}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
                            <Text style={styles.content}>{val.adress}</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.content}>{val.text}</Text>
                        </View>
                    </View>

                })

                return (
                    <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.containerScroll}>
                        {data}
                    </ScrollView>
                );
            }
        } else {
            return <View style={styles.contentWrapper}>
                <Text style={styles.content}>Not connected!</Text>
            </View>
        }
    }
};
```

This code prints data if device is connected to internet.
What I need to do is if device is conneted to internet, fetch data from URL and store (or overwrite) it in AsyncStorage, and then print data on screen. If device is not connect to the internet just print data from AsyncStorage.

This is example of .json I call from URL:

```
[
    {
        "type": "Party",
        "title": "New party comming to town!",
        "adress": "New Yrok",
        "date": "20. 4. 2019.",
        "image": "https:\/\/some-url.com\/some-image.jpg",
        "text": [
            "Some description"
        ],
        "_id": "events_1"
    }
]
```

I can't find any similar solution, so I would be greatfull if someone has tutorial that could help me with this.

**EDIT (little more of explenation):**

This is what I want to do:
If device is connected to the internet, update AsyncStorage with data from URL and then display that new data in AsyncStorage. If device is not connected to the internet, just display data that is AsyncStorage. And there are multiple "events", not just one like in the example.

Comment: Thank you, can you show me how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store your response like this

note one thing when you set value into `AsyncStorage` you need to store as string `JSON.stringify()` value into storage.

```
    onSave = async () => {
           try {
                await AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(responseData));
                Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
            } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
            }
        }
```

and when you get value from `AsyncStorage` you need to `JSON.parse()`

```
onSave = async () => {
    try {
                const storedValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem("key");
                this.setState({ storedValue: JSON.parse(storedValue) });
            } catch (error) {
                Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
            }
}
```

hope it will help you

Comment: Same example can be found in documentation of React Native. I was hoping for more detailed explenation, like how to store multiple events (same as one in the example) in storage and display it. And where should I put that part of code. This looks like funcinos you would call on button press, but I need to setItems after fetch, and then getItems. I have structure how elements should be printed for each event, I want it the same way from multiple events (not just one), but with data from AsyncStorage, not directly from URL. The idea is having screen with all events, but option to update them.

Comment: You can make use of https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#multiget to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```js
export default class BankDetails extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      userToken: null,
      userData: {
        nameOfBank: '',
        account_umber: '', 
        account_holder_ame: ''
      }
    }
  }
  
  async componentDidMount () {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userData')
      let userDetails = JSON.parse(value)
      if (userDetails !== null) {

        let userData= Object.assign({}, this.state.userData)
        userData.nameOfBank = userDetails.nameOfBank
        userData.account_umber = userDetails.account_umber
        userData.account_holder_ame = userDetails.account_holder_ame

        this.setState({
          userToken: userDetails.token,
          userData
        })
      }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
  } 
  onBankChange = (nameOfBank) => {
    this.setState({userData: {...this.state.userData, nameOfBank:nameOfBank}})
    }
  saveBankDetailsEdit = () => {
    const  { nameOfBank,account_umber, account_holder_ame }= this.state.userData
    let {userToken} = this.state
  
    var formData = new FormData()
    formData.append('bank', nameOfBank)
    formData.append('account_number', account_umber)
    formData.append('account_title', account_holder_ame)
  
    fetch('http://xxxx/update', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'X-API-KEY': '123456',
        'Authorization': userToken
      },
      body: formData
    }).then(function (response) {
       console.log(response)
       AsyncStorage.getItem('userData').then(
        data => {
          data = JSON.parse(data)
          data.nameOfBank = nameOfBank
          data.account_umber = account_umber
          data.account_holder_ame = account_holder_ame
          AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(data))
        }
      )
       let data = JSON.parse(response._bodyText)
       Alert.alert(data.message)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    })
    .done()
  }
```

This is how I have done my job. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is what I want to do:
If device is connected to the internet, update AsyncStorage with data from URL and then display that new data in AsyncStorage. If device is not connected to the internet, just display data that is AsyncStorage. And there are multiple "events", not just one like in the example.